# html в ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ng-repeat

балуюсь с angularjs, возник вопрос с ng-repeat, а конкретно с выводом html внутри цикла. В моем случае это s.body

```
<svg id="test" ng-controller="SvgList">
<symbol id="{{s.idItem}}" vbox="{{s.viewBox}}" ng-repeat="s in test" >
  {{s.body}}
</symbol>
```

```
var app = angular.module('App', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('SvgList', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.test = [{
    idItem: 'triangle',
    viewBox: '0 0 20 20',
    body: '<path d="M 0,0 L 18,10 L 0,20z"></path>'
  }]
}]);
```

[тут живой пример на plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NCkZZE4PK22EGLirHbqR?p=preview)

пробовал использовать ng-bind-html="s.body", но на выходе пустота

версии использовал эти

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.4/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

решение найдено

```
 app.filter('trustAsHtml',['$sce', function($sce){
  return function (text){
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);  
  };
 }]);
```

в html

```
<symbol id="{{s.idItem}}" vbox="{{s.viewBox}}" ng-repeat="s in symbols" ng-bind-html="s.body|trustAsHtml"></symbol>
```